# Disable right click in Galleria Fullscreen theme

Tags: jquery, galleria

I'm using Drupal 7 and Galleria fullscreen theme for my images. I don't want click right and save images. So, i added this code in my jQuery file:

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

This function working on my site images but not working on Galleria fullscreen. This is my Galleria fullscreen js:

```
(function($) {

Galleria.addTheme({
    name: 'fullscreen',
    author: 'Galleria',
    version: '2.0',
    css: 'galleria.fullscreen.css',
    defaults: {
        transition: 'fade',
        image_crop: true,
        thumb_crop: 'height'
    },
    init: function(options) {

        this.addElement('thumbnails-tab');
        this.appendChild('thumbnails-container','thumbnails-tab');

        var tab = this.$('thumbnails-tab');
        var loader = this.$('loader');
        var thumbs = this.$('thumbnails-container');
        var list = this.$('thumbnails-list');
        var infotext = this.$('info-text');
        var info = this.$('info');

        var OPEN = false;
        var POS = 0;

        if (Galleria.IE) {
            this.addElement('iefix');
            this.appendChild('container','iefix');
            this.setStyle(this.get('iefix'), {
                zIndex:3,
                position:'absolute',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity:.4
            })
        }

        if (options.thumbnails === false) {
            thumbs.hide();
        }

        var fixCaption = this.proxy(function(img) {
            if (!(img || img.width)) {
                return;
            }
            var w = Math.min(img.width, $(window).width());
            infotext.width(w-40);
            if (Galleria.IE && this.options.show_caption) {
                this.$('iefix').width(info.outerWidth()).height(info.outerHeight());
            }
        });

        this.bind(Galleria.RESCALE, function() {
            POS = this.stageHeight - tab.height()-2;
            thumbs.css('top', OPEN ? POS - list.outerHeight() + 2 : POS);
            var img = this.getActiveImage();
            if (img) {
                fixCaption(img);
            }
        });

        this.bind(Galleria.LOADSTART, function(e) {
            if (!e.cached) {
                loader.show().fadeTo(100, 1);
            }
            $(e.thumbTarget).css('opacity',1).parent().siblings('.active').children().css('opacity',.5);
        });

        this.bind(Galleria.LOADFINISH, function(e) {
            loader.fadeOut(300);
            this.$('info,iefix').toggle(this.hasInfo());
        });

        this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {
            fixCaption(e.imageTarget);
        });

        this.bind(Galleria.THUMBNAIL, function(e) {
            $(e.thumbTarget).click(function() {
                if (OPEN) {
                    tab.click();
                }
            });
        });

        this.trigger(Galleria.RESCALE);

        this.addIdleState(thumbs, { opacity:0 });
        this.addIdleState(this.get('info'), { opacity:0 });

        if (Galleria.IE) {
            this.addIdleState(this.get('iefix'), { opacity:0 });
        }

        this.attachKeyboard({
            up: function(e) {
                if (!OPEN) {
                    tab.click();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            down: function(e) {
                if (OPEN) {
                    tab.click();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        this.$('image-nav-left, image-nav-right').hover(function() {
            //$(this).animate({opacity:1},100);
        }, function() {
            //$(this).animate({opacity:0});
        }).show();

        tab.click(this.proxy(function() {
            tab.toggleClass('open', !OPEN);
            if (!OPEN) {
                thumbs.animate({
                    top: POS - list.outerHeight() + 2
                },400,'galleria');
            } else {
                thumbs.animate({
                    top: POS
                },400,'galleria');
            }
            OPEN = !OPEN;
        }));

        this.$('thumbnails').children().hover(function() {
            $(this).not('.active').children().css('opacity', 1);
        }, function() {
            $(this).not('.active').children().fadeTo(200, .5);
        }).children().css('opacity',.5)

        this.enterFullscreen();
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

How disable right click in my Galleria fullscreen mode?

Comment: Is the Galleria an "img" or are the images encased in another block? Whatever that Galleria block is, you probably need to bind on that element. Explore the DOM in Developer Tools to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u try using live instead of bind? that way the img that match your selector will have it always

```
$('img').live('contextmenu', function(e){
return false;
```

});

[Jquery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: `.live()` method is nowadays deprecated.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are right! Thanks for pointing that out! it should be .on() instead of live 
$(document).on('contextmenu', 'img', function(){return false;});

Answer (score 3):

try with:

```
$('.galleria-images').on('contextmenu','img',function(e){
   alert('Images you are attempting to download are copyrighted material.');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the right click like this

```
$('body').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
       case 3: return false; break;
    }
});
```